# How does sklearn log_loss know the order of probabilities?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

Consider the example from the sklearn documentation for log_loss:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import log loss
log_loss(["spam", "ham", "ham", "spam"], [[.1, .9], [.9, .1], [.8, .2], [.35, .65]])
```

Running this, we get an output of ~0.216. The model is reasonably good at classifying ham and spam.

How does sklearn know that the first probability is `ham` and the second is `spam`?

If I wanted to flip the labels, i.e. the first is `spam` and the second is `ham`, how could I do that? Explicitly supplying the labels argument does not work:

```py
log_loss(["spam", "ham", "ham", "spam"], [[.1, .9], [.9, .1], [.8, .2], [.35, .65]], labels=["ham", "spam"])
```

Output: 0.216.

```py
log_loss(["spam", "ham", "ham", "spam"], [[.1, .9], [.9, .1], [.8, .2], [.35, .65]], labels=["spam", "ham"])
```

Output: 0.216.

Note this is not a question about the order of the truth labels as per [this question on the stats Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/321333/log-loss-function-in-scikit-learn-returns-different-values), but a question about the order of the probabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sklearn.metrics.log_loss` assumes that the labels for probabilities are in alphabetical order. This can be seen in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L1600).

To flip your labels, you need to rename them in the opposite alphabetical order, e.g. `aspam` and `bham`:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
log_loss(["aspam", "bham", "bham", "aspam"], [[.1, .9], [.9, .1], [.8, .2], [.35, .65]])
```

Output: ~1.816.

Comment: Going to the source code before checking the relevant [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) is arguably overkill.